# Configuração white label no Route53 da AWS

Tags: domínio, amazon-aws

Alguém que tenha conhecimento em Amazon AWS e tenha utilizado o Route53 sabe a maneira correta de configurar nameservers próprios na ferramenta?

> Ex.: ns1.meudominio.com; ns2.meudominio.com; ns3; ns4... etc

Segui todos os procedimentos [especificados na documentação do serviço](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html) e mesmo assim não consegui. Também [cheguei a assistir um vídeo no canal do Youtube oficial da AWS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahnhoFgd5K4), foi possível reproduzir todos os passos e deixar tudo conforme explicado, porém não funciona.

O domínio que estou tentando configurar: **oregionalsul.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema sozinho, fiz duas perguntas pois ambas são tópicos isolados, porém a forma de resolução é a mesma. 
Respondi em minha outro pergunta que foi um problema posterior a esta configuração, confira.

**Resposta em:**

> [Problema em nameserver: "missing nameservers reported by parent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239105/problema-em-nameserver-missing-nameservers-reported-by-parent/240418#240418)

Seguindo estes passos você conseguirá tanto configurar o WhiteLabel na AWS, quanto evitar o problema de missing nameservers reported by parent, que acontece após a configuração do WhiteLabel.