# Problema em nameserver: "missing nameservers reported by parent"

Tags: hospedagem, dns, amazon-aws

Estou utilizando Amazon AWS com a ferramenta Route53 para gerenciar os registros de minha zona DNS. Consegui configurar a listagem dos nameservers e a resposta deles em solicitações de ping, porém ao realizar um teste no [**IntoDNS**](https://intodns.com/oregionalsul.com) me deparo com este erro, que talvez seja a razão de os nameservers não conseguirem resolver os nomes.

Alguém já teve problema semelhante e conseguiu resolver de alguma forma? Já pesquisei muito, porém sem sucesso.

[image: Erro nos registros]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como esta pergunta não recebeu respostas, informou que consegui solucionar o problema sozinho. Compartilho aqui minha solução para outras pessoas que passam pela mesma situação.

> Problema: **"Missing nameservers reported by parent"** e **"Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers"**.

Acontece que no Route53 da AWS (Amazon) o gerenciamento dos nameservers é um pouco diferente. Você não pode utilizar no painel de seu domínio (Registro.br, Whois, GoDaddy, etc) os nameservers da AWS. No início das configurações você os utiliza para que consiga acessar o servidor e realizar instalações, etc. Após configurar todos os registros DNS é necessário alterar.

### Na prática, o que estou falando

[image]
O Route53 lhe fornecerá alguns nameservers únicos após criar uma zona hospedada para seu domínio. Acontece que os mesmos não possuem autoridade sobre seu domínio, eles apenas encaminham. Para resolver este problema você DEVE configurar seus próprios nameservers da seguinte forma.

Acesse o Route53, clique na zona hospedada de seu domínio e deixe os registros igual da imagem abaixo:

[image]

> 1. Edite seu registro do tipo NS e cadastre os nameservers que deseja utilizar. Ex.: ns1.meudominio.com.br / ns2.meudominio.com.br / ns3 / ns4... etc.
> 2. Edite seu registro do tipo SOA e substitua o início da linha pelo **ns1** que você acabou de criar (veja na imagem, linha 3)
> 3. Crie um registro para cada nameserver criado (no caso temos 4 nameservers [ns1, ns2, ns3 e ns4] , então serão 4 registros do tipo A. Em name coloque: ns1 e em VALUE adicione o ip que leva ao nameserver. Veja abaixo como obter os ips para cada nameserver.

#### Obter ip do nameserver

Envie solicitações de ping no Windows, Linux ou Mac utilizando do terminal. Você vai utilizar os nameservers da [imagem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cek7S.png).

Ex.: `ping ns-1190.awsdns-20.org`

[image]

- Repita este processo com cada um dos nameservers fornecidos pelo AWS Route53.
- Anote os ips e o tempo de resposta (tempo) fornecidos no processo de ping.
- Agora vamos ordenar os nameserver do menor tempo de resposta (assim sabemos qual é melhor para ser utilizado como principal, depois secundário, terceiro, etc.)

### Aqui está o segredo

Quando toda esta configuração estiver correta, vá ao seu painel de domínio (Whois, Registro.br, GoDaddy), clique para informar os nameservers (cada painel tem uma forma diferente, não tenho como detalhar cada um). Em meu caso é o painel Whois. Basta informar os nameservers que acabamos de criar (ns1.meudominio.com.br, ns2, ns3, ns4), salve e pronto! Problema resolvido.

*As alterações podem levar até 48 horas para propagarem, então aguarde.

[image]

### Nameservers filhos

Para garantir, utilizei do painel Whois e adicionei os Child Nameservers, cada um apontando para seu respectivo IP. Isto pode ser um passo um tanto quanto desnecessário, porém achei melhor garantir.

[image]

*Os ips informados foram obtidos no passo de ping.